# Query Performace Counter Sleeping Issue

Tags: c++, winapi

Hello I am trying to loop through a piece of code at a certain rate.  In this example my goal is to execute my block of code 120 times per second.  I have implemented this and I use a counter to see how many loops I complete per cycle and I am getting 220 times per second.  Here is my code...USERUPDATE is a constant that is 1/120.0f and timeInterval is USERUPDATE in nanoseconds and I convert all my time values to nanoseconds for sleep_for(nano())...

```
LARGE_INTEGER grabCpuTicks;
unsigned long long globalInterval;
unsigned long long timeInterval = (unsigned long long)(USERUPDATE*1000000000.0f);

LARGE_INTEGER cyclePerSecond;
LARGE_INTEGER ElapsedNanoSeconds;
LARGE_INTEGER PreviousNanoSeconds;

QueryPerformanceFrequency( &cyclePerSecond);

QueryPerformanceCounter(&grabCpuTicks);
PreviousNanoSeconds.QuadPart = grabCpuTicks.QuadPart;

int counter = 0;
loopTimer->setTime();


while(true)
{


    //Keyboard user input updates
    bool *keys = input->GetKeys();
    bool *mouse = input->GetClicks();
    Vector drawPos;
    double fireStrength;
    Vector temp = GetAngPos();


    if(!mouse[0] && fire && currObj != NULL)
    {
        fire = !fire;
        fireTime->setTime();
    }
    else if(mouse[0] && !fire && currObj != NULL)
    {
        Vector pos(player->GetLinPos().getx(), player->GetLinPos().gety() - 3.0f*USERHEIGHT/4.0f, player->GetLinPos().getz());

        fireStrength = fireTime->getTime()*800.0f;
        if(fireStrength > MAXSPEED)
        {
            fireStrength = MAXSPEED;
        }
        currObj = items->getNext(currObj);
        currObj->mesh->SetTrajectory(pos,GetAngPos(),fireStrength, NULL);
        fire = !fire;
    }


    //If second has passed
    if(loopTimer->getTime() >= 1.0f)
    {
        cout << "Number of loops per second: " << counter << endl;
        counter = 0;
        loopTimer->setTime();
    }
    counter++;



    QueryPerformanceCounter(&grabCpuTicks);
    ElapsedNanoSeconds.QuadPart = grabCpuTicks.QuadPart - PreviousNanoSeconds.QuadPart;

    //reset tick count for next timing interval
    PreviousNanoSeconds.QuadPart = grabCpuTicks.QuadPart;

    //convert to nano seconds
    ElapsedNanoSeconds.QuadPart *= 1000000000;
    //Divide by CPU Cycles per second
    ElapsedNanoSeconds.QuadPart /= (cyclePerSecond.QuadPart);

    globalInterval = ElapsedNanoSeconds.QuadPart;

    //Global interval compensates for time computing so the timestep
    //is actually in whole correct including computation time and sleep time
    if(timeInterval > (globalInterval))
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds(timeInterval - globalInterval));
    }



}
```

Comment: I am using it in this line of code...                              //Divide by CPU Cycles per second
ElapsedNanoSeconds.QuadPart /= (cyclePerSecond.QuadPart);

Comment: Sleeping generally isn't very accurate past a handful of milliseconds (e.g. ~15 on Windows).

Comment: To achieve that sort of accuracy you'd be better off busy looping on the value returned by QueryPerformanceCounter.

Comment: Yes I was originally looping on the value of performance counter but it was taking 10% more of the CPU time.   I have three loops like this so the performance goes from about 8% CPU to 38%.  Kind of a performance drop haha.  Disappointing that sleep is unpredictable...why bother making it if its crap?

Answer (score 0):

The Windows `Sleep` function has a very low resolution. You need a high resolution timer. The usual solution is to use a [multimedia timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd743609.aspx).

If that is not high enough a resolution then you will need a busy loop and timing with a performance counter.

Comment: But I believe a multimedia timer only supports 1 millisecond resolution and i would prefer at least microseconds...Any other suggestions?

Comment: Why are you waiting until after you've got answers to specify your question. Please can you list all your requirements in the question. It is lazy to do it your way and wastes our time.

Comment: I have been playing with the idea of doing all my computations in a consecutive loop say 2400 times with the goal of 2400 computations per second.  I would then sleep the rest of the time leftover to complete a full second.  Only problem is I am simulating a real time collision system and would then only get one simulation frame per second.  I then thought to split up the 2400 cycles into 60 frames (2400/60) so essentially compute 2400/60 cycles then sleep for whatever was left over of 1/60 of a second.  This causes dependencies so I'm not confident with this approach.